Putting a deep path dir based Twig file in the sub theme directory directly
In my sub theme, a file I find myself change a lot is MY_SUB_THEME_DIR/templates/layout/page.html.twig.
It is currently in a "deep path" of directories in my sub theme but I want to access it more shortly from /MY_SUB_THEME_DIR directly. How to do that correctly?

What do you mean by "access it"? To edit it?

No, I mean that I want Drupal to access it from /MY_SUB_THEME_DIR/page.html.twig instead of from /MY_SUB_THEME_DIR/templates/layout/page.html.twig.

What does it matter where Drupal accesses the file from? This post says "I want".

Sorry, I meant I want to access it.

Another way to put it is I want to use this file from /MY_SUB_THEME_DIR instead from MY_SUB_THEME_DIR/templates/layout.

You could make a symbolic link on Linux filesystems:
cd MY_SUB_THEME_DIR
ln -s templates/layout/page.html.twig .

